# accessing value and addrss of contained array in struct using pointers - C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void int_array(int *arr)
{
    *arr=10;
    *(arr+1)=20;
}
struct struct_ex
{
    int i;
    char arr[5];

};
void struct_array(struct struct_ex *arr)
{
    
    arr->i=10;
    arr->arr[0]='a';
    arr->arr[1]='b';
    (arr+1)->i=20;
    (arr+1)->arr[0]='c';
    (arr+1)->arr[1]='d';
    
}


int main()
{

    int *arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    int_array(arr);
    printf("%d %d\n",*arr,*(arr+1));
    
    struct struct_ex *arr_struct=malloc(sizeof(struct struct_ex)*2);
    struct_array(arr_struct);
    printf("- %d %c,%c\n",arr_struct->i,arr_struct->arr[0],arr_struct->arr[1]);
    printf("- %d %c,%c\n",(arr_struct+1)->i,(arr_struct+1)->arr[0],(arr_struct+1)->arr[1]);
    
    printf("- %d %c,%p\n",(arr_struct+1)->i,(arr_struct+1)->arr[0],(arr_struct+1)->arr+1);
    
    
    
    
    return 0;

}
```

output is

```
10 20
- 10 a,b
- 20 c,d
- 20 c,0x564d8b7c46e1
```

But I want the output should be like below

```
10 20
- 10 a,b
- 20 c,d
- 20 c,d
```

How to print character `d` insead of `0x564d8b7c46e1` in last line of the above wanted output

Comment: `(arr+1)->i` -> `arr[1].i`

Comment: also does passing struct pointer in function call what get passed: the value or the address

Comment: What does "I want the value outputs from" mean? It's not clear what value you actually want to print.

Comment: @kaylum with using `(arr_struct+1)->arr+1` in printf with %d access specifier prints wrong value or gives error when program compiled with `-Wall Wextra -Werror` so I want the value and not the address because now it prints address of `(arr_struct+1)->arr+1` in printf I want only value of `(arr_struct+1)->arr+1` which should be character `d`

Comment: what does it mean when you say " does not work" not running ? error ? print what is not intended ?

Comment: @NevoGoldman it prints `0x55b8dce6f2b1` but I want the value which should be character `d`

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't work because it doesn't try to work as it is intentionally printing the address. Show us the code that you tried to use to print the value.

Comment: @kaylum see my question `printf("- %d %c,%p\n",(arr_struct+1)->i,(arr_struct+1)->arr[0],(arr_struct+1)->arr+1);` prints `20 c,0x55b8dce6f2b1`

Comment: its the last line

Comment: Yes but you intentionally use `%p` but then you say you don't want to print the address. So what is the code you have that attempts to print the value but then "doesn't work"?

Comment: @NevoGoldman entire code in my question plus the output.

Comment: If you want the output to be `d` you need to reform the last line as such: `printf("- %d %c,%c\n", (arr_struct + 1)->i, (arr_struct + 1)->arr[0], (arr_struct + 1)->arr[1]);`

Comment: @NevoGoldman ok please check my question one more time. I tried my best to explain

Comment: @user786 You must use the `%p` Format Specifier ?

Comment: `If you want the output to be d you need to reform the last line as such: printf("- %d %c,%c\n", (arr_struct + 1)->i, (arr_struct + 1)->arr[0], (arr_struct + 1)->arr[1]);`  then its error: `error: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘char *’`

Comment: But the want characeter `d` not the address because `p` will print address see my question its printing `0x564d8b7c46e1` if I use %p

Comment: @kaylum see my answer...and please check if its ok

Comment: can anyone please tell if `0x564d8b7c46e1` is correct or not correct in my question

Comment: `arr->arr[0]='a';` <<-- you are confusing yourself by using identical names for the struct pointer and one of its members. Invent better names.

Comment: @wildplasser thank u for the comment. Can u please look at my answer I tried and it looks to me that there is no problem because nothing printed on compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror pointer1.c` but I will will keep in mind better names in work which I was trying for sometime and failing. This question was required because of that thing I was trying.

Comment: Also: most people prefer array/index notation because it is more readable than pointer dereferencing : `*(ptr+1) = 10;` **-->>**  `ptr[1] = 10;`

Comment: @wildplasser and also is there any compile time option with gcc or with any open-source tool to print the addresses of functions and things when I compile c and c++ program. I really like to know, this will be very helpful. I did discovered `radare2` on my previous destro but now I use Ubuntu

Comment: @wildplasser sometiime when I work with code I find it difficult with array/index notation. So I resort to pointers

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was this

```
printf("- %d %c,%c\n",(arr_struct+1)->i,(arr_struct+1)->arr[0],*(arr_struct+1)->arr+1);
    
    if((*(arr_struct+1)->arr+1)=='d')
    printf("correct\n");
```

full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void int_array(int *arr)
{
    *arr=10;
    *(arr+1)=20;
}
struct struct_ex
{
    int i;
    char arr[5];

};
void struct_array(struct struct_ex *arr)
{
    
    arr->i=10;
    arr->arr[0]='a';
    arr->arr[1]='b';
    (arr+1)->i=20;
    (arr+1)->arr[0]='c';
    (arr+1)->arr[1]='d';
    
}


int main()
{

    int *arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    int_array(arr);
    printf("%d %d\n",*arr,*(arr+1));
    
    struct struct_ex *arr_struct=malloc(sizeof(struct struct_ex)*2);
    struct_array(arr_struct);
    printf("- %d %c,%c\n",arr_struct->i,arr_struct->arr[0],arr_struct->arr[1]);
    printf("- %d %c,%c\n",(arr_struct+1)->i,(arr_struct+1)->arr[0],(arr_struct+1)->arr[1]);
    
    printf("- %d %c,%c\n",(arr_struct+1)->i,(arr_struct+1)->arr[0],*(arr_struct+1)->arr+1);
    
    if((*(arr_struct+1)->arr+1)=='d')
    printf("correct\n");
    
    
    
    return 0;

}
```

required output achieved

```
10 20
- 10 a,b
- 20 c,d
- 20 c,d
correct
```